# Using Google App Engine as a CDN

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm building a static site which deploys to Google App Engine. Are there any advantages of storing the assets (js, css, imgs) in CloudStorage. All of the assets are going be under 32MB (if thats a limit).

Based on [this slide](https://dl.google.com/io/2009/pres/W_1115_From_Spark_Plug_To_Drive_Train_Life_of_an_App_Engine_Request.pdf) (slides 24-28), it sounds like requests for static assets of a GAE app would use Google's special infrastructure designed for serving static assets. However its not clear about how its performance compares to Google CloudStorage.

Any clarifications on this would be much appreciated. Similar questions on Stackoverflow exists, but they are fairly dated (2010), and Google's Cloud products have changed since then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting your cache headers will result in similar performance AFAIK. 
Both GAE and GCS use [Google Edge cache](https://peering.google.com/about/delivery_ecosystem.html).

GCS is probably easier to manage your static resources, whereas it takes a redeploy to GAE to add/remove static resources.

Other important note : GCS as CDN does not work over HTTPS with custom domains. GAE does support HTTPS with custom domains.